# cannot get data from redis cache

Tags: node.js, typescript, callback, es6-promise, node-redis

I am calling readData function from controller file to get data from cache.When i tried to use the someVal after readData function,i am getting undefined firstly and then after callback response it is getting the data and call gets remains in unhandled promise rejection state.I want lines after readData function to be executed only after data is available.

```
import redis from 'redis'
const client = redis.createClient();

//cacheserive.ts
const readData = async (key,callback) =>{
try{
const res = await client.get(key)
if(res === null){
callback(new Error('failed to get data'));
}else{
callback(null,JSON.parse(res));
}
}catch(err){
    console.log(err)
}
}

//test.controller
let newObj = {};
let someVal;
readData("key",(_err,result) =>{
someVal = result.data
});
newObj[someval]= "1233"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your console statement into the callback for `readData`.

This is a timing issue where console.log is called before the read has completed.

Comment: can you explain now